# boost::spirit parsing double with separated sign

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I'm using boost::spirit to parse text into doubles whose sings may be separated from the numbers by blanks.

Using or misusing [real_policies](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.real._code__phrase_role__identifier__realpolicies__phrase___code__expression_requirements), i found a solution but i'm not sure if there's a easier way to achieve it.
Can someone please give me a hint?

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/0JNJFE)

Here's the relevant code fragment:

```
template <typename T>
struct real_with_separated_sign_policies : boost::spirit::qi::real_policies<T>
{
    // allow skipping chars between a possible sign and a folling real number
    template <typename Iterator>
    static bool parse_sign(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last)
    {
        bool ret = qi::extract_sign(first, last);
        if (ret)
            qi::parse(first, last, *qi::lit(' '));
        return ret;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct RealWithSeparatedSignParser
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, double(), Skipper>
{
    boost::spirit::qi::real_parser<double, real_with_separated_sign_policies<double> > RealWithSeparatedSignValue;

    RealWithSeparatedSignParser() : RealWithSeparatedSignParser::base_type(start)
    {
        start %= RealWithSeparatedSignValue;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), Skipper> start;
};

int main() {
    std::string str = " -  1.234 ";
```

Comment: @GuyGreer i can't follow; when i replace "start %= RealWithSeparatedSignValue" with "start %= qi::double_" i don't get the double parsed. How can the "global" skipper be used to do that and wouldn't it hurt other parser sections?

Comment: Disregard my comment, I tested it and what I said was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do this exactly like you did here. You should consider restoring the `first` iterator in case the further parsing fails.

You might want to double check flush semantics on `multi_pass<>` adapted iterators (I think it's okay, because the wrapping `real_parser` must be able to backtrack on failure down the road anyways).

---

Of course, given the simplicity of the grammar, the sample can be reduced, but that's hardly the point I suppose.

Here's a shorter demo showing a more generic skipping policy (using `blank_type` by default):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d884bec98932d8f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename T, typename Skipper = qi::blank_type>
struct skip_after_sign_policies : boost::spirit::qi::real_policies<T> {
    // allow skipping chars between a possible sign and a folling real number
    template <typename Iterator>
    static bool parse_sign(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last) {
        return qi::extract_sign(first, last)
            && qi::phrase_parse(first, last, qi::eps, Skipper {});
    }
};

int main() {
    qi::real_parser<double, skip_after_sign_policies<double> > grammar;

    std::string const str = " -  1.234 ";

    auto it = str.begin();
    double value;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(it, str.end(), grammar, qi::space, value);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok << " " << value;
    if (it != str.end())
        std::cout << "Remaining: '" << std::string(it, str.end()) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
true -1.234
```

Comment: Added a more generic skipping policy (using `blank_type` by default): [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d884bec98932d8f)

Comment: great answer! I especially like the added genericness after the edit. I tried to validate the backtracking and think you're right there as well:) Here's the code: http://ideone.com/QuBbcP